Explain post-selected teleportation
I'd be grateful for an explanation of post-selected teleportation (PCTCs). Please provide a step-by-step description of how the process should be performed (Alice and Bob style). Please also explain exactly where the time travel is supposed to occur, and why it does or does not constitute or simulate time travel.
I am not a physicist, but please assume I have a basic understanding of quantum teleportation and of QM in general.
Post-selected teleportation is described in an article named The quantum mechanics of time travel through post-selected teleportation, and a practical experiment demonstrating a nonclassical advantage is proposed in Nonclassical Advantage in Metrology Established via Quantum Simulations of Hypothetical Closed Timelike Curves.

"Please provide a step-by-step description... Please also explain exactly..." You have not asked a question. This is a question-and-answer website, not a place to make unfocussed demands.

The authors of the article refer to another article in which they explain what they're talking about:

A curious feature of teleportation is that, whenever Alice’s Bell measurement gives the same result it would when measuring the initial shared state, then Bob’s unitary $V$ is the identity. In this case, Bob does not have to perform any transformation to obtain Alice’s state $|\psi\rangle$: in some sense, Bob possesses the unknown state even before Alice implements the teleportation! Causality is not violated because Bob cannot foresee Alice’s measurement result, which is completely random. However, if we could pick out only the proper result with probability one, the resulting ‘projective’ teleportation would allow information to propagate along spacelike intervals, to escape from black holes [8], or to travel backwards in time along a closed timelike curve. We call this mechanism a projective or post-selected CTC, or P-CTC.

There is a pretty standard of teleportation in Nielsen and Chuang's book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information", Section 1.3.7. Alice and Bob each have one qubit from a pair of qubits, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ respectively, entangled in a Bell state. Alice can transmit an unknown quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ of a qubit $Q_1$ to Bob by the following steps:

Alice performs a controlled not from $Q_1$ onto $Q_2$
she performs a Hadamard gate on $Q_1$
she measures $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ and sends the measurement results $M_1,M_2$ to Bob
Bob then performs the operation $Z^{M_1}X^{M_2}$ on $Q_3$ which ends up in the state $|\psi\rangle$.

According to this description, if Alice gets 0 for both measurement results, Bob does nothing to his qubit and it is somehow in the state $|\psi\rangle$. The authors of the paper you linked describe this as Bob having the state in advance and if he somehow could select only the state in which the Alice gets 00.
This is the typical morass of confusion that people get into when they start talking about collapse in quantum theory. Collapse contradicts the equations of motion of quantum theory so if you wanted a collapse theory you would have to modify those equations if you were going to have a real law of physics and not ad hoc nonsense. The process they describe directly contradicts quantum theory with or without closed timelike curves and they have given no account of the theory they are replacing it with. There is nothing to explain.
There is only one known account of what is happening in reality when teleportation takes place. That account uses quantum theory without modifying it with collapse. Lack of quantum interference on macroscopic scales is explained by decoherence, not collapse:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
This account explains that teleportation involves sending locally inaccessible quantum information in decoherent channels. That quantum information doesn't suffer decoherence because it doesn't change the expectation values of the decoherent channels in which it is carried:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

There is a lot to parse in your question(s), more certainly than be covered in an answer here.  I will do my best to give you a useful take on the following, linked here in PDF form with images:
The quantum mechanics of time travel through post-selected teleportation
First, this paper is old (2010) and should not be considered definitive of anything.  Pure theory, and its title is somewhat misleading as presented. From the early part of the paper:
"A well-known quantum communication channel is given by quantum teleportation, in which shared entanglement combined with quantum measurement and classical communication allows quantum states to be transported between sender and receiver. We show that if quantum teleportation is combined with post-selection, then the result is a quantum channel to the past. The entanglement occurs between the forward- and backward-going parts of the curve, and post-selection replaces the quantum measurement and obviates the need for classical communication, allowing time travel to take place."
Quantum teleportation and its close cousin, entanglement swapping, are based on a well known protocol using a Bell State Measurement (or BSM, sometimes BSA, which is the same as what is described in the first sentence of the quote above).  The following reference is a more standard treatment of the BSM and the swapping (teleportation) protocol:
High-fidelity entanglement swapping with fully independent sources
First thing to understand: Your cited paper really has little or nothing to do with the theory behind quantum teleportation. On the quantum theory side, there is no relevance to the temporal ordering of events.  If you chose to think of the teleportation as a channel, it is future to past as much as it is past to future. Any other description is not generally accepted, and is simply a function of preferred quantum interpretation (CI, MWI, BM, etc).  There is no time travel.
Second, as your reference states in its conclusion: "Our hope in elaborating the theory of P-CTCs is that this theory may prove useful in formulating a quantum theory of gravity, by providing new insight on one of the most perplexing consequences of general relativity, i.e., the possibility of time-travel."  I.e. the paper is really about quantum gravity, a subject that has been studied relentlessly by thousands of scientists in the past 40 years - to absolutely no avail as of today (other than a lot of false hopes). Einstein's GR still stands tall today, and it has no quantum component.  So this paper, now 14 years old, is one of those dead ends.  No intention here to make light of this work or the authors, but it is just one of literally hundreds I have seen touching on similar lines of thought.
Lastly: The closest you get to "time travel" today is in the quantum world - and no one really thinks of it as time travel.  There are many Delayed Choice experiments that have been executed per quantum theory, such as this well-known experiment (this team was cited in your reference):
Experimental delayed-choice entanglement swapping
In this experiment, pairs of photons are entangled after they are detected.  That is considered "quantum steering into the past".  This effect is real, but is not time travel.
In short: Hypothetical Closed Timelike Curves are just that: hypothetical, like many ideas around GR - but don't really much have to do with standard generally accepted theory today.  So there is really nothing to explain, just one of many speculative ideas floated out there over the last few decades that haven't gone anywhere as of yet.
This may not be the answer you are looking for, but it is at least generally accepted science.  If you would find it helpful, I would be glad to edit the answer to explain quantum teleportation itself in more detail in case my references don't do the trick (their descriptions can come across a bit cryptic).
